# WebAuthn JSON API call not working on Android Webview after deploying Ionic through Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webauthn

I have implemented WebAuthn API using Angular-Ionic App in frontend and Spring Boot as backend. Webauthn is working fine when I am accessing the site from the browser.

But when I have created an Android App using Cordova Plugin, the call of Webauthn API is just not happening.

I am using '@github/webauthn-json' library and calling the create(..) and get(..) method of webathn-json API.

Service class that communicates with webauthn-json library

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { create, CredentialCreationOptionsJSON, CredentialRequestOptionsJSON, get, PublicKeyCredentialWithAssertionJSON, PublicKeyCredentialWithAttestationJSON } from "@github/webauthn-json";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebAuthnAuthenticatorService
{
    async registerCredentialToAuthenticator(credentialCreationOptions: CredentialCreationOptionsJSON):
    Promise<PublicKeyCredentialWithAttestationJSON>{
        console.log(`Inside WebAuthnAuthenticatorService calling create before`);
        return await create(credentialCreationOptions);
    }

    async getCredentialFromAuthenticator(credentialRequestOptions: CredentialRequestOptionsJSON):
    Promise<PublicKeyCredentialWithAssertionJSON>{
        return await get(credentialRequestOptions);
    }
}
```

My Component Class

```
 -- 

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-registration',
    templateUrl: './registration.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./registration.page.scss']
})
export class RegistrationPage
{

    constructor(private messageService: MessagesService,
        private httpClient: HttpClient, 
        private webauthnService: WebAuthnAuthenticatorService){}

    async registerNew(username: string):Promise<void>
    {
        const loading = await this.messageService.showLoading('Starting registration ...');
        await loading.present();

        let body = new HttpParams();
        body = body.set('username', username);

        this.httpClient.post<RegistrationStartResponse>('registration/start', body)
        .subscribe(async (response) => {
            await loading.dismiss();
            if (response.status === 'OK') {
                await this.createCredentials(response);
            } else if (response.status === 'USERNAME_TAKEN') {
                loading.dismiss();
                this.messageService.showErrorToast('Username already Registered');
            }
        },
        (error: any) => {
            console.log(`Error Object ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
            loading.dismiss();
            this.messageService.showErrorToast('Registration failed:'+error.error.message);
          },
          () => loading.dismiss()
        )
    }

    private async createCredentials(response: RegistrationStartResponse): Promise<void>{
        console.log(`Registration Start Response = ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
        let credential:any;
        //try{
          credential = await this.webauthnService.registerCredentialToAuthenticator({
            publicKey: response.publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions
          });
          console.log(`Getting Credential from Authenticator : ${JSON.stringify(credential)}`);
        /*}catch(e){
          console.log(`Error returned from Create : ${JSON.stringify(e)}`);
        }*/
        
        

        /*try {
            // @ts-ignore
            credential.clientExtensionResults = credential.getClientExtensionResults();
          } catch (e) {
            // @ts-ignore
            credential.clientExtensionResults = {};
          }*/

        this.finishRegistration(response.registrationId,credential);
    }

    private async finishRegistration(registrationId:string,credential:any):Promise<void>{
        const credentialResponse = {
            registrationId: registrationId,
            credential
          };

          const loading = await this.messageService.showLoading('Finishing registration ...');
          await loading.present();
      
          this.httpClient.post<RegistrationFinishResponse>('registration/finish', credentialResponse)
            .subscribe(response => {
              if(response.success){
                this.messageService.showInfoToast('Registration Successful');
              }else{
                this.messageService.showErrorToast('Registration failed');
              }
            }, (error: any) => {
              loading.dismiss();
              this.messageService.showErrorToast('Registration failed. '+error.error.message);
            }, () => loading.dismiss());
    }
}
```

RegistrationStartReponse and RegistrationFinishResponse is coming from the server -- The model is simple as below --

```
    export interface RegistrationStartResponse {
    status : 'OK' | 'USERNAME_TAKEN';
    registrationId?: string;
    publicKeyCredentialCreationOptions: any;
}

export interface RegistrationFinishResponse {
    success :boolean;
}
```

I have used Ionic 6.19.0 and Cordova 11 to create hybrid app to run on Android. The App is running but the call to create(..) and get(..) is not happening.

It seems that Android Webview is not supporting the WebAuthn Json API.

-- Is it possible to write a custom Cordova plugin to have it supported? I am new to Ionic and Cordova also

-- Is Chrome Custom Tab support the Web-Authn. Is it possible to create the app from cordova that will launch in Chrome Custom Tab instead of WebView?

Comment: please post complete code, not just fragments. There's not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: I have edited the Questions. Waiting for any answer / suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that Android Webview is not supporting the WebAuthn Json API.

This is indeed [not supported](https://crbug.com/1284805) (yet!). I would advise starring the bug to get updates.

> Is it possible to write a custom Cordova plugin to have it supported?

You could create an ionic plugin that talks to the native [FIDO2 API](https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps), bridging the feature gap. I'm not familiar with ionic, but if you can hook into native Android code, you can do it. This is probably the way I'd go about it.